# Ember API documentation is missing template helper functions

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm a new to Ember and maybe i'm missing something, but since version 3.1 (https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers) i can't find documentation for helpers yield and with and some others (3.4: https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.4/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers). I read a changelog and could't find any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a bug documentation for some methods got dropped between 3.1 and 3.4 releases. There is a list in a [Github Issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/16993). Most of them got fixed a few days ago with [this Pull Request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/17002). There wasn't a release of API docs yet and therefore the docs are not updated yet.